# SQL Query to COUNT all rows with duplicate values broken down by primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have two tables my database. One is a list of drivers and one is a list of violations.
Each violation has a status, either yellow or red and I need to count the number of yellow violations and red violations that a particular driver has and ORDER BY either red or yellow ASC or DESC.

Drivers Table:
AutoID (primary key and foreign key to violations table driverID)
clientID
employerID

Violations Table:
violationID (primary key)
status
driverID (foreign key to autoID in Drivers table)

I ran the query below to get all the red or yellow violations

```
SELECT d.autoID, d.clientID, v.status FROM edsp_drivers d, edsp_violations v 
WHERE d.employerID='000000028' AND d.autoID=v.driverID 
AND (v.status = 'yellow' OR v.status='red') 
ORDER BY d.autoID ASC
```

Results as follows:

```
autoID          clientID    status

000000206   000000015   Yellow

000000206   000000015   Red

000000206   000000015   Yellow

000000206   000000015   Yellow

000000206   000000015   Yellow

000000206   000000015   Yellow

000000206   000000015   Yellow

000000206   000000015   Yellow

000000206   000000015   Yellow

000000206   000000015   Yellow

000000207   000000015   Yellow

000000207   000000015   Yellow

000000367   000000015   Yellow

000000367   000000015   Yellow

000000367   000000015   Red

000000368   000000015   Red

000000369   000000015   Yellow

000000369   000000015   Yellow

000000369   000000015   Red

000000369   000000015   Yellow

000000369   000000015   Yellow

000000369   000000015   Yellow

000000398   000000015   Yellow

000000398   000000015   Yellow
```

What I need to do is count all the yellow or red alerts grouped by driver and ORDER BY red/yellow DESC - this is where I am stuck.

Hopefully someone can help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to group by driver and violation color:

```
SELECT d.autoID, v.status, COUNT(v.status)
FROM edsp_drivers d
LEFT JOIN edsp_violations v 
    ON d.autoID = v.driverID 
    AND (v.status = 'yellow' OR v.status='red')
WHERE d.employerID = '000000028' 
GROUP BY d.autoID, v.status
ORDER BY v.status ASC, COUNT(v.status) DESC
```

Comment: Almost there. I actually wanted to ORDER BY highest number of red alerts at the top, then highest yellow alerts.

Comment: Thanks for the direction though. I modified as follows. 

SELECT v.driverID, v.status, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM edsp_drivers d
JOIN edsp_violations v 
    ON d.autoID = v.driverID 
    AND (v.status = 'yellow' OR v.status='red')
WHERE d.employerID = '000000028' 
GROUP BY v.driverID, v.status
ORDER BY v.status ASC, count DESC

Comment: only issue with this is now it doesn't list those driver who have neither a red or yellow alert. How do we address that?

I want to list all the drivers in the system, for this clientID, with those drivers with most red alerts at the top of the list.

Comment: @nematoth see update, use `LEFT JOIN`, `COUNT(v.*)` and group by `d.autoID`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT d.autoID
     , SUM( CASE WHEN v.status = 'yellow' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Yellow_Count
     , SUM( CASE WHEN v.status = 'red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Red_Count
FROM edsp_drivers d, edsp_violations v 
WHERE d.employerID='000000028' AND d.autoID=v.driverID 
AND (v.status = 'yellow' OR v.status='red')
GROUP BY d.autoID
ORDER BY d.autoID ASC;
```

Comment: You need `SUM` instead of `COUNT`

Comment: I like this.. but it doens't list the driver with 0 yellow alerts and 0 red alerts..

Comment: Remove the `AND (v.status = 'yellow' OR v.status='red')` and see result :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use group by clause and count function , below is the constructed query

```
 SELECT count(*) as count, v.status FROM edsp_drivers d, edsp_violations v 
WHERE d.employerID='000000028' AND d.autoID=v.driverID 
AND (v.status1 = 'yellow' OR v.status1='red') 
group by v.status
ORDER BY  v.status ASC
```